# What does T::* signify in the declaration of a function parameter list?

Tags: c++, qt, callback, void, point-cloud-library

I declare a particular keyboard callback function as this inside my code:

```
void keyboardEventCallback(const pcl::visualization::KeyboardEvent &event, void* viewer_void, void* widget_void);
```

The keyboard event is the actual event passed to the callback function, the viewer_void parameter is a pointer to a PCLVisualizer class that generates a window for rendering, and widget_void is a pointer to a widget that interfaces with Qt.

In the documentation for pcl, a registration function passes the arguments for registering the keyboard function like

```
boost::signals2::connection registerKeyboardCallback(void(T::*callback)(const pcl::visualization::KeyboardEvent&, void*), T& instance, void* cookie=nullptr)
```

So my question is, **what is the meaning of `T::*` inside the registration function declaration**, and **why am I not allowed to pass this:**

```
m_vis->registerKeyboardCallback(keyboardEventCallback, (void*)&m_vis, (void*)this);
```

where `m_vis` is a visualizer, `keyboardcallback` is the callback, and this is the widget.

Why can I not register like this. This is for the point cloud library.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> what is the meaning of T::* inside the registration function declaration

This is the syntax of a pointer to member. Let's take a look at the whole type and name of the parameter:

```
void(T::*callback)(const pcl::visualization::KeyboardEvent&, void*)
```

This is the declaration of a variable named `callback`. It's a *pointer to member function*. More precisely, it's a pointer to member function of the class `T`.

If we take the name out of the type, we see things more clearly:

```
// class name ---v     v------- parameters
            void(T::*)(const pcl::visualization::KeyboardEvent&, void*)
//          ^---- return type
```

It's  in fact, a pointer to function member of the class `T` that returns `void`. It's a function that takes *strictly* two parameters: a `const pcl::visualization::KeyboardEvent&` and a `void*`.

> why am I not allowed to pass this

It's simple. Look at the type of your function:

```
using func_type = decltype(keyboardEventCallback);
// hint: the type is: void(*)(const pcl::visualization::KeyboardEvent&, void*, void*)
```

Let's compare the two types side by side:

```
void(*)(const pcl::visualization::KeyboardEvent&, void*, void*)
void(T::*)(const pcl::visualization::KeyboardEvent&, void*)
```

First, your function is not a member function, it's a plain function pointer. It's not the same type. Then, you got three arguments, as the type of the parameter only ask for two. This is different.

---

**Now, how can you fix this??**

You could use a lambda:

```
auto myCallback = [](const pcl::visualization::KeyboardEvent& e, void* c) { /* ... */ }

using lambdaType = decltype(myCallback);

// Be careful here, we don't want our lambda to go out of scope when it is called.
m_vis->registerKeyboardCallback(&lambdaType::operator(), myCallback, this);
```

---

Or  even simpler: just define `keyboardEventCallback` inside your class, and send it:

```
// don't forget: keyboardEventCallback must receive the same parameter as asked.
m_vis->registerKeyboardCallback(&MyClass::keyboardEventCallback, *this, this);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the syntax for member functions.

Example:

```
class A{
  int giveMe5();
};

&A::giveMe5;  // will be of type int(A::*)()
```

Why does the type differ from free functions and static member functions ?
Because member functions have an implicit parameter that points to the object on which the function gets called.

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types
says:

> The type of this function is different depending on whether it is an ordinary function or a non-static member function of some class:
>    -  Its type is `int (*)(char,float)` if an ordinary function
>    -  Its type is `int (Fred::*)(char,float)` if a non-static member function  of class Fred

Comment: This is very valuable additional insight! It would be useful if you copy-pasted and quoted (with `> my quote`) the content of the link instead of just linking to it. Even a screenshot might be ok, although in this case quoting is best and not difficult.