# c++ template parameters: template <typename T, T* T::*next, T** T::*prev>, what does it mean?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm learning c++ template, and found such code snippet:

```
template <typename T, T* T::*next, T** T::*prev>
struct I_P_List_adapter
{
  static inline T **next_ptr(T *el) { return &(el->*next); }
  static inline const T* const* next_ptr(const T *el) { return &(el->*next); }
  static inline T ***prev_ptr(T *el) { return &(el->*prev); }
};
```

the second and third parameters are not like some typenames, look so strange, so what does it mean?

Comment: `T::*` is pointer-to-member.

Comment: See [What does <T::* int> mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34091875/what-does-t-int-mean) and also [What does T::* signify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40136180/what-does-t-signify-in-the-declaration-of-a-function-parameter-list)

Comment: Offtopic: This `I_P_List_adapter` sucks since it doesn't work with smart pointers.

Comment: @MarekR double sucks because `next` and `prev` are different types

Comment: @Caleth quadruple, because it requires `next` and `prev` to be public. Its only purpose seems to be that you can write `next(x)` rather than `&(x->*next)` and similar for the ohters. Imho a lot of complexity with little flexibility for very little gain.

Comment: well, not even that. Its rather `&(x->*next)` vs `I_P_List_adapter<T,&List_type::next,&List_type::prev>::next_prt(x)`

Comment: thanks all, yet another question: what are the next and prev? types or variable names?

Comment: They are names for non-type template parameters

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Well it can be `I_P_List_adapter<List_type,&List_type::Foo,&List_type::Bar>`, so it at least fixes up inconsistencies in spelling

Comment: thanks all, I have totally got it. `T* T::*next` just like `int N` parameter, the integer type paramters in template. sometime mistaken by the lowercase style names.